# Bot won't leave voice channel when left alone

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a personal music bot that plays music for me and friends, I only have a play and leave commands which both work perfectly, but I was wondering if a little upgrade to the bot automatically leaving voice channel when left in it alone was possible. After some reading in documentation, I thought I got it but this piece of my code simply doesn't work, it's almost like python is ignoring it for some reason so I guess I am missing something here...
so I was wondering if there is a reason why my code:

```
    @client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member):
    voice_state = member.guild.voice_client
    if len(voice_state.channel.members) == 1:
        await voice_state.disconnect()
```

won't work, I don't get any error messages and literally nothing happens. Is it all as it should be here?

Comment: I would try logging that voice_state.channel.members object. I could be totally wrong, but I think that may refer to the total number of members in the channel, not the ones actively using it...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some arguments for this event. Simply add `before` and `after` and you should be fine.

The full event could be:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    voice_state = member.guild.voice_client
    if voice_state is not None and len(voice_state.channel.members) == 1:
    # If the bot is connected to a channel and the bot is the only one in the channel
        await voice_state.disconnect() # Disconnect the bot from the channel
```

You can see more in the docs here:

- [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_sta#discord.on_voice_state_update)

Comment: Thanks, it helped very much! Also, I had an issue of my own wherein my code client.event was actually bot.event so that changed things a lot also and explained why python would completely ignore my code lol, forgot I changed it

Comment: While the suggestions here are correct, they don't really address the problem. If the lack of arguments was the problem, it would throw an error when called.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs OP said it was an error on his side due to incorrect usage of `bot` and `client`. Maybe this was the solution and there was nothing wrong with the code. However, you should "call" those arguments, even if you do not use them.